# I burned out the USB ports -- can I salvage the motherboard?

Tags: usb, motherboard, hardware-failure

I had a general purpose computer ( no hardcore gaming and such, just some 3d modeling ) from ~2009, running windows7, quad core2 2.40GHz, 4GB Ram, motherboard GA-P35-DS3R.

Yet I managed to connect +12 volts to the USB ports and they burned out - i.e. usb ports are not working any more, none of them, not on front, not on back. Everything else seems working fine, connected mouse and keyboard to PS2 ports.

If I understand correctly, I should go shopping for a new motherboard now. The one I have seems to have a the Socket 775 connection to the CPU and DDR2 RAM. Yet I can't find any modern motherboards with this connection, is it obsolete, right?

Therefore, should I be shopping for a new motherboard, new CPU and new RAM? Or is there any way to salvage what I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yet I managed to connect +12 volts to the USB ports and they burned out - i.e. usb ports are not working any more, none of them, not on front, not on back. **Everything else seems working fine,** connected mouse and keyboard to PS2 ports.

(Boldface mine.)

I think the key is in the boldfaced statement above. **Assuming that you are correct in your assessment** that everything else is working fine, you should be able to **get an offboard USB controller card,** plug it in and just use those USB ports instead of the ones integrated on the motherboard.

If that works, you won't need to buy a new motherboard with all of what that will likely entail (CPU, RAM, etc.; basically a whole new computer, except for storage and offboard peripherals like the graphics card). Yes, coming by a Socket 775 CPU and compatible RAM in known good condition is likely to be tricky.

Of course, there might be other reasons why you might want to upgrade your 2009 vintage system, but if it does what you need it to and all you need is a new set of USB ports, then an offboard controller should do the job. It's also a relatively cheap thing to try, and **worst case you will have a few extra USB ports for the new system.** Given the prevalence of USB-connected hardware, I'd say you for all practical purposes cannot have *too many* USB ports on a modern computer.

Comment: You might want to consider the cost of the new usb controller vs the cost of a new motherboard, given that the latter can be quite cheap (even for powerful/configurable ones); it's possible that more damage was done that you're not currently aware of.

Comment: @Poldie I can get a 2-port PCIe USB3.0 controller card for about $40 including VAT, plus shipping. The *cheapest* ATX AMD-socket motherboards I can find from that same supplier is the Asus M5A97 970 R2.0 AM3+ at about $115 or the Asus F2A55 A55 S-FM2 at about $85. This entire answer is based on the OP's assertion that "everything else seems [to be] working fine"; if that is incorrect, then the whole answer fails.